# An empty if statement

Tags: matlab, loops, if-statement

I have this set up:

```
for i=1:10
    if (condition1)

    elseif (condition2)
        (do something)
    else
        (do something)
    end
end
```

For `condition1`, if the condition is met I don't want anything to happen, I just want to run the loop again with the next value of `i`. How do I go about this? Can I just leave it blank below the `if` statement, or is there a more elegant way to do this? If I remove the first `if` statement, what would happen during the loop if none of the other conditions are met?

If possible I would like to avoid running the first `if` statement, as for my problem it has the highest complexity. It is essential I check `condition1`, because if it is met then I want to move onto the next value of `i`. I hope this question makes sense.

Comment: I think leaving an empty if is perfectly fine. I would add a comment inside explaining that in this case nothing has to be done, so when you come back to the code after some time you will not wonder why there is an empty if.

Comment: Stewie Griffin answer explains why is bad to **remove** the first conditional (which causes undesired bechaviour).  I am saying that **leaving it empty** (or better with a comment) is perfectly fine

Comment: Personally I like the approach where a line is left empty, with only a comment that nothing is done. This does only apply if I have more code in the loop, below the if statement and this code should be run always. In case I want to highlight that I want to go to the next iteration I would have continue. And in case the code is complex, then skipping things is not the best approach. It is better to divide the code into functions. This will make each function shorter and easier to overview. Good naming will make the user able to read the code without diving into each subfunction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use the `continue` statement, this skips the current iteration of the loop:

```
for i=1:10

    if (condition)
        continue;

    elseif (condition)
        (do something)

    else 
        (do something)

    end
end
```

See: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/matlab/matlab_continue_statement.htm

Comment: Adding `continue` is only relevant if there is something else done in the loop after the `end` statement of the `if`-construct, which you do not want to be executed.

Comment: It might be worth to note that continue will skip the rest of the code inside the innermost loop and go directly to the end of this iteration.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from ialquaz is the correct one (in my opinion), so no need to elaborate that. Instead, I'll answer you second question:

> If I remove the first if statement, what would happen during the loop
>   if none of the other conditions are met?

This depends on what your conditions are but in general, YES!

This is because the last `else` catches all the cases where none of the other conditions are met. For instance, suppose you have the following loop:

```
n = 9;
x = zeros(1,n);
for ii = 1:n
    if ii < 3
        continue;
    elseif ii > 5
        x(ii) = 4;
    else 
        x(ii) = 6;
    end
end
x =    
   0   0   6   6   6   4   4   4   4
```

As you can see, in the start, the `continue` statement makes the loop skip the last `elseif` and `else`. That means that the first 2 elements will not be touched. `elseif ii > 5` will result in all the elements higher after `ii == 6` will be set to `4`. When `ii >= 3 & ii <= 5` the `else` will catch the remaining cases, so those elements will be `6`. Now, let's have a look at what happens if we skip the first `if`:

```
n = 9;
x = zeros(1,n);
for ii = 1:n
    if ii > 5
        x(ii) = 4;
    else 
        x(ii) = 6;
    end
end
x =
   6   6   6   6   6   4   4   4   4
```

The first three elements are not covered by the first `if` statement anymore, and are therefore caught bu the `else`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to skip `condition2` if `condition1` is true, simply ask for the opposite:

```
for i = 1:10
    if ~(condition1)
        if (condition2)
            (do something)
        else 
            (do something)
        end
    end
end
```

The `~` ("not") will turn `true` to `false`, and the other way around. Since you want to execute both statements blocks (before and after the `else`) of `condition2` only if `condition1` is `false`, you have to check for it explicitly in each iteration.

Comment: I tried this and re-ran the program and my output completely changes for some reason. The problem is, if the first if statement is met I don't want to continue with the current loop, I want to move onto the next value of i. But when I remove it and condition 2 isn't met, then it does the computations under the 'else', which I don't want.

Comment: @EBH What about using `if ~cond1&&cond2` `elseif ~cond1` `end`?

Comment: @Crowley obviously, there are much more than one way to do this, the OP will have to decide what is most readable to him. However, your suggestion could be less efficient if `cond2` is complex.

Comment: @EBH Or if `cond1` is complex. But if it is complex you should put it in a separate variable and give it a meaning full name. This improves readibility.

Comment: @Bernhard I'm not the OP, so I don't know what meaning this conditions have. When I said complex I ment to the execution time, if it takes a lot of time to check `condition2` then placing it inside `condition1` eliminates unnecessary checks of it.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i=1:10
    if (condition) && ~(condition1)
        (do something)
    elseif ~(condition1)
        (do something)
    end
end
```

You can do it in above way as well

Comment: This will not work, as the statements after the `else` will be executed whenever   `~(condition) = false`.

Comment: @EBH, thanks for pointing that out. I edited it, hope it should be ok now.

Comment: `elif` should be `elseif`, and also there is no optimization here, both `condition1` and `condition2` are checked in each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

If condition1 happens to be true and if 'true' you don't want to do anything, you don't need that in the code. So I'll go with something like this:

```
for i=1:10
    //commenting 'if' for condition1 since you wouldn't need it
    //if (condition1)

    if (condition2)
        (do something)
    else
        (do something)
    end
end
```